# How to use cypress, scrollTo in Ionic App?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, scroll, cypress

For a test in **Cypress** I want to scroll down to the bottom of the page created with **Ionic**.

I have tried using scrollTo on the window:

```
cy.scrollTo('bottom')
```

But got an error:
**Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.scrollTo() failed because this element is not scrollable:**<window>

Using scrollIntoView on the element itself, did not help either.

Also scrolling the main ionic container:

```
cy.get('ion-content').scrollTo('bottom')
```

resulted in the same error.

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the main div in shadow root inside the ion-content container did the trick for me:

```
cy.get('ion-content').shadow().find('main').scrollTo('bottom')
```

It seems to be the container which is actually scrollable

Answer (score 1):

If you set the focus inside the ion-content for example by clicking any element inside it then you can use `.scrollIntoView()`.